# SQL Left Join non null value only if non null value exsist

Tags: sql, subquery, left-join

I am working with GEO Location variables and I believe this should be a lot simpler than I am making this.

I want to return a row, and left join three other "options" to it as other values, this is done by using the geo location of the user and a few options will be different depending on this.  All options will have a default, so I only want to override the default if I match the geo

table 1 will have items such as burger, hotdog while table 2 will be something like toppings, and each item will have up to three layers of toppings, some will be altered depending on geo location.

table one

```
   |id | name   |
   ______________
   |0  | burger |
   |1  | hotdog |
```

table two

```
   |topid | topping | layer | location
   ___________________________________
   | 0    | catsup  | 1     | 
   | 1    | mustard | 2     | 
   | 2    | onion   | 3     | 
   | 3    | lettuce | 3     | US
   | 4    | bacon   | 3     | CA


$geo = 'CA';
```

mySql

```
SELECT item.name, layer1.topping as `layer1`, layer2.topping as `layer2`, layer3.topping as `layer3` 
FROM `one` item
LEFT JOIN `two` layer1 
ON layer1.layer = 1
AND layer1.location IS NULL OR layer1.location = $geo
LEFT JOIN `two` layer2 
ON layer2.layer = 2
AND layer2.location IS NULL OR layer2.location = $geo
LEFT JOIN `two` layer3 
ON layer3.layer = 3
AND layer3.location IS NULL OR layer3.location = $geo
WHERE item.id = 0
```

My outcome would be to only return a burger with catsup, mustard and have bacon at the layer3 topping so I need a if there is a NULL value and a letter value take the letter value as the layer, otherwise take the NULL.  I hope to do this without having nested selects in the query for speed of returning 500+ records

Comment: If each item has toppings, then I would expect an `itemid` in the second table.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue in your query in that the `OR`ed part of the `JOIN` conditions should be in parentheses to get the result you want i.e. the conditions should look like:

```
ON layer1.layer = 1
AND (layer1.location IS NULL OR layer1.location = $geo)
```

Once this is fixed, your query will produce multiple rows, dependent on the presence of a row in `two` which matches `$geo`. You can sort these rows on whether the location for each layer is `NULL`, resulting in the row which matches the most locations being the first row. You can then use `LIMIT 1` to select only that row:

```
SELECT item.name, layer1.topping as `layer1`, layer2.topping as `layer2`, layer3.topping as `layer3` 
FROM `one` item
LEFT JOIN `two` layer1 
ON layer1.layer = 1
AND (layer1.location IS NULL OR layer1.location = '$geo')
LEFT JOIN `two` layer2 
ON layer2.layer = 2
AND (layer2.location IS NULL OR layer2.location = '$geo')
LEFT JOIN `two` layer3 
ON layer3.layer = 3
AND (layer3.location IS NULL OR layer3.location = '$geo')
WHERE item.id = 0
ORDER BY layer1.location IS NULL,
         layer2.location IS NULL,
         layer3.location IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Output (for your sample data, assuming `$geo = 'CA'`):

```
name    layer1  layer2      layer3
burger  catsup  mustard     bacon
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pbbcwF2TEXfKyEywT3Q5x7/0)

If you need to get this for all `item.id` values, you *will* need to use a nested `SELECT`. This is one way it can be done:

```
SELECT item.name, layer1.topping as `layer1`, layer2.topping as `layer2`, layer3.topping as `layer3` 
FROM `one` item
LEFT JOIN `two` layer1 
ON layer1.layer = 1
AND (layer1.location IS NULL OR layer1.location = 'CA')
LEFT JOIN `two` layer2 
ON layer2.layer = 2
AND (layer2.location IS NULL OR layer2.location = 'CA')
LEFT JOIN `two` layer3 
ON layer3.layer = 3
AND (layer3.location IS NULL OR layer3.location = 'CA')
JOIN(
SELECT item.name,
       MIN((layer1.location IS NULL) + (layer2.location IS NULL) + (layer3.location IS NULL)) AS mostspecific
FROM `one` item
LEFT JOIN `two` layer1
ON layer1.layer = 1
AND (layer1.location IS NULL OR layer1.location = 'CA')
LEFT JOIN `two` layer2 
ON layer2.layer = 2
AND (layer2.location IS NULL OR layer2.location = 'CA')
LEFT JOIN `two` layer3 
ON layer3.layer = 3
AND (layer3.location IS NULL OR layer3.location = 'CA')
GROUP BY item.name
) sp ON item.name = sp.name AND (layer1.location IS NULL) + (layer2.location IS NULL) + (layer3.location IS NULL) = sp.mostspecific
```

Output:

```
name    layer1  layer2  layer3
burger  catsup  cheese  bacon
hotdog  catsup  cheese  bacon
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pbbcwF2TEXfKyEywT3Q5x7/2)

Note `$geo` should be in quotes, otherwise it will be treated as a column name. Also, as Gordon pointed out in the comments, it would seem that table `two` should have an `itemid` so that you can link toppings to particular items (in case you don't want e.g. bacon to be a valid topping for a hot dog).

Comment: Will the order by at the end work if returning say both items as in returning multiple rows as the limit 1 will retutn just the one.  Would SELECT DISTICT work to return the first value for mutiple rows?

Comment: @RadiumChris If you mean without the `WHERE` clause on `item.id`, no, it won't. You didn't mention that option in your question... do you need the query to work in that scenario? If so, you will have to use nested SELECTS.

Comment: @RadiumChris what variety of SQL are you using? MySQL, SQL server, ??? and what versionf?

Comment: I am running MySQL 5.7, I was hoping there was something i was missing to allow a quick fix, i may do nested selectors or just return 6 "toppings" (a null and geo version) and if statement them in php to display correct values.  Speed is pushing so much on web side I think I over think to many pieces now.

Comment: Not in 5.7. In 8+ you could use row numbers and a CTE to allow easy filtering. Otherwise you can filter in PHP by simply taking the first row you encounter for each item using the ordering shown in my query.

Comment: @RadiumChris Actually, if you don't have item specific toppings, you could just use `LIMIT n` where n is the number of items you have.

Comment: @RadiumChris In fact, without item specific toppings, the results for `layer1`, `layer2` and `layer3` will be identical for all items, so you can still use the original query and just apply the result to all items

Comment: @RadiumChris I've modified the answer with a query which will work for all items and can be modified for item-specific toppings fairly readily.

Comment: Thanks for the update and I see a path I can take, as far as all items being the same I simplified my actual query way down to point out the specific issue I am running into, real code has 1000's of "toppings" being joined by a one to many table that then runs into the simplified geo issue.  I will look at speed of the sub queries vs returning a non geo and geo topping for all three and using php to show correct one.